# How to create a Photoshop and illustrator Smart Object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, vector, layers, shapes

i was download psd flat vector design, and i open it, the layer is smart object, double click on thumbnail, and switch over automatically open in adobe illustrator as vector witch have many layer. My question is how to make the smart object that can open automatically in adobe illustrator like that. i try to make it but i can't. i make shape layer and convert it to smart object and double click on it just open new tab in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy Illustrator contents and paste them in Photoshop.

Photoshop will ask you what format you prefer.

Choose the Smart Object option.

Also, you can drag it from Illustrator to Photoshop.

Note: We cannot create this kind of Smart Object inside Photoshop because every Smart object created inside Photoshop will be edited in Photoshop (when we double click on it). The reason your specific Smart Object is edited in Illustrator is because it was created in Illustrator first.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer LeoNas. Do i have to make shape or vector in illustrator first? is it possible to only make it (shape or vector) in Photoshop and can be opened automatically in the illustrator?

Answer (score 0):

> the layer is smart object, double click on thumbnail, and switch over automatically open in adobe illustrator as vector witch have many layer.

- First of all let me clear that Smart Objects aren't layer, They're barely objects(files) and photoshop only contains it's links.
- When we edit smart objects, Photoshop orders system to execute the file when we edit the smart objects. i.e. you've placed vector then it'll execute file with .ai extension that's why it launched illustrator.

> My question is how to make the smart object that can open automatically in adobe illustrator like that. i try to make it but i can't.

- If you want to open Adobe Illustrator then all you have to do is make smart object which contains adobe illustrator files (.ai/.eps) @LeoNas already mentioned how to do this stuff.

> i make shape layer and convert it to smart object and double click on it just open new tab in Photoshop.

- You've made shape layer and then converted it to smart object so basically photoshop saved your shape layer as .psb file so whenever you'll edit it photoshop will open .psb file and that's why you're getting it opened in another window.

Hope it helps to clear the doubts about Smart Objects. I didn't mentioned how to place shapes from illustrator to photoshop since it's already answered.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: wow this is great explanation @Mr.Online, i'am a newbie for photoshop and illustrator. So the psd file that I downloaded was made in the illustrator first? I'm just curious how to make it. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Yeah! Basically every designer (I'm UI/UX designer too) uses pipeline where illustrator are linked with photoshop. The main reason is the shapes and illustrations. Photoshop shape layer isn't sufficient enough to make a very good illustrations like characters and etc so we first draw it in Illustrator. Then we drag and drop whole character to photoshop which creates smart objects. It's same as above mentioned. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Illustrator is great at vector art thus it is bad at doing raster effects like brushing and other pixel effects and also Illustrator uses CMYK color model which isn't clearly for digital images and it's normally used for printing purposes while Photoshop is beast on raster effects thus we use illustrator for flat colored shapes and then we use photoshop to colorize them properly

Comment: This is very helpful @Mr.Online, i do appreciate. Big thanks and regards.